# Mocking $modal in AngularJS unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm writing a unit test for a controller that fires up a `$modal` and uses the promise returned to execute some logic. I can test the parent controller that fires the $modal, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to mock a successful promise.

I've tried a number of ways, including using `$q` and `$scope.$apply()` to force the resolution of the promise. However, the closest I've gotten is putting together something similar to the last answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490150/angular-ui-bootstrap-testing-a-controller-that-uses-a-dialog) SO post;

I've seen this asked a few times with the "old" `$dialog` modal.
I can't find much on how to do it with the "new" `$dialog` modal.

Some pointers would be tres appreciated.

To illustrate the problem I'm using the [example provided in the UI Bootstrap docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), with some minor edits.

**Controllers (Main and Modal)**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularUiModalApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $modal, $log) {
        $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

        $scope.open = function() {

            $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    items: function() {
                        return $scope.items;
                    }
                }
            });

            $scope.modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
                $scope.selected = selectedItem;
            }, function() {
                $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });
        };
    })
    .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
        $scope.items = items;
        $scope.selected = {
            item: $scope.items[0]
        };

        $scope.ok = function() {
            $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
        };

        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    });
```

**The view (main.html)**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>I is a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
</div>
```

**The test**

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function() {

    // load the controller's module
    beforeEach(module('angularUiModalApp'));

    var MainCtrl,
        scope;

    var fakeModal = {
        open: function() {
            return {
                result: {
                    then: function(callback) {
                        callback("item1");
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };

    beforeEach(inject(function($modal) {
        spyOn($modal, 'open').andReturn(fakeModal);
    }));


    // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _$modal_) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            $modal: _$modal_
        });
    }));

    it('should show success when modal login returns success response', function() {
        expect(scope.items).toEqual(['item1', 'item2', 'item3']);

        // Mock out the modal closing, resolving with a selected item, say 1
        scope.open(); // Open the modal
        scope.modalInstance.close('item1');
        expect(scope.selected).toEqual('item1'); 
        // No dice (scope.selected) is not defined according to Jasmine.
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi , in case that i want to test the modalInstance controller ( in this case ModalInstanceCtrl ) , what is the best way to do so ?

Comment: Itsak: I turned your comment into a full question. I'm stuck on that, too. Question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24373220/736963

Comment: my 5 cents with jasmine >= 2 you should use  spyOn($modal, 'open').and.callFake(fakeModal);

Answer (score 91, accepted):

When you spy on the $modal.open function in the beforeEach,

```
spyOn($modal, 'open').andReturn(fakeModal);

or 

spyOn($modal, 'open').and.returnValue(fakeModal); //For Jasmine 2.0+
```

you need to return a mock of what $modal.open normally returns, not a mock of $modal, which doesn’t include an `open` function as you laid out in your `fakeModal` mock. The fake modal must have a `result` object that contains a `then` function to store the callbacks (to be called when the OK or Cancel buttons are clicked on). It also needs a `close` function (simulating an OK button click on the modal) and a `dismiss` function (simulating a Cancel button click on the modal). The `close` and `dismiss` functions call the necessary call back functions when called.

Change the `fakeModal` to the following and the unit test will pass:

```
var fakeModal = {
    result: {
        then: function(confirmCallback, cancelCallback) {
            //Store the callbacks for later when the user clicks on the OK or Cancel button of the dialog
            this.confirmCallBack = confirmCallback;
            this.cancelCallback = cancelCallback;
        }
    },
    close: function( item ) {
        //The user clicked OK on the modal dialog, call the stored confirm callback with the selected item
        this.result.confirmCallBack( item );
    },
    dismiss: function( type ) {
        //The user clicked cancel on the modal dialog, call the stored cancel callback
        this.result.cancelCallback( type );
    }
};
```

Additionally, you can test the cancel dialog case by adding a property to test in the cancel handler, in this case `$scope.canceled`:

```
$scope.modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
    $scope.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
    $scope.canceled = true; //Mark the modal as canceled
    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

Once the cancel flag is set, the unit test will look something like this:

```
it("should cancel the dialog when dismiss is called, and $scope.canceled should be true", function () {
    expect( scope.canceled ).toBeUndefined();

    scope.open(); // Open the modal
    scope.modalInstance.dismiss( "cancel" ); //Call dismiss (simulating clicking the cancel button on the modal)
    expect( scope.canceled ).toBe( true );
});
```

Comment: brilliant! Thanks so much. I had completely missed what the open function actually returned and that I was trying to mock $modal itself. This makes perfect sense. I had been battling with this for ages and can now see a way forward. Appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm happy it worked for you. Hopefully UI Bootstrap will provide a default $modal mock that we can use in the future.

Comment: Instead of having `$scope.selected = selectedItem;` in the result of the modal, I have a service call `SessionService.set('lang', selectedItem);`. Is it possible to test if the service has been called right after `scope.modalInstance.close('FR');`?

Comment: @lightalex You can use a Jasmine spy on the 'set' function of your service, and then expect it to have been called. Similar to this: `spyOn( SessionService, 'set' ).andCallThrough();
scope.modalInstance.close('FR');
expect( SessionService.set ).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Comment: Having some trouble on this. My scope.modalInstance is undefined..are you guys are getting a valid modalInstance?

Comment: @MattKim Yes, scope.modalInstance was defined and working in my test.

Comment: This test works great, any ideas for testing the ModalInstanceController? I have scope functions within the instance controller so I wanted to test them, but am getting an error when attempting to inject `$modalInstance`.

Comment: Instead of mocking the modal instance, I'd like to get a real modal instance opened with my template, then get a reference to the modal DOM element.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 9):

To add to Brant's answer, here is a slightly improved mock that will let you handle some other scenarios.

```
var fakeModal = {
    result: {
        then: function (confirmCallback, cancelCallback) {
            this.confirmCallBack = confirmCallback;
            this.cancelCallback = cancelCallback;
            return this;
        },
        catch: function (cancelCallback) {
            this.cancelCallback = cancelCallback;
            return this;
        },
        finally: function (finallyCallback) {
            this.finallyCallback = finallyCallback;
            return this;
        }
    },
    close: function (item) {
        this.result.confirmCallBack(item);
    },
    dismiss: function (item) {
        this.result.cancelCallback(item);
    },
    finally: function () {
        this.result.finallyCallback();
    }
};
```

This will allow the mock to handle situations where...

You use the modal with the `.then()`, `.catch()` and `.finally()` handler style instead passing 2 functions (`successCallback, errorCallback`) to a `.then()`, for example:

```
modalInstance
    .result
    .then(function () {
        // close hander
    })
    .catch(function () {
        // dismiss handler
    })
    .finally(function () {
        // finally handler
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Since [modals](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) use promises you should definitely use [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) for such things.

Code becomes:

```
function FakeModal(){
    this.resultDeferred = $q.defer();
    this.result = this.resultDeferred.promise;
}
FakeModal.prototype.open = function(options){ return this;  };
FakeModal.prototype.close = function (item) {
    this.resultDeferred.resolve(item);
    $rootScope.$apply(); // Propagate promise resolution to 'then' functions using $apply().
};
FakeModal.prototype.dismiss = function (item) {
    this.resultDeferred.reject(item);
    $rootScope.$apply(); // Propagate promise resolution to 'then' functions using $apply().
};

// ....

// Initialize the controller and a mock scope
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    fakeModal = new FakeModal();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        $modal: fakeModal
   });
}));

// ....

it("should cancel the dialog when dismiss is called, and  $scope.canceled should be true", function () {
    expect( scope.canceled ).toBeUndefined();

    fakeModal.dismiss( "cancel" ); //Call dismiss (simulating clicking the cancel button on the modal)
    expect( scope.canceled ).toBe( true );
});
```

Comment: This works for me and is the best way to mock promises

Comment: I don't see $rootScope defined in FakeModal, so how is it accessible in close and dimiss functions? Sorry, I am new to Angular and Jasmine and I feel it has something to do with scope inheritance but I can't see how FakeModal gets it.

Answer (score 2):

Brant's answer was clearly awesome, but this change made it even better for me:

```
  fakeModal =
    opened:
      then: (openedCallback) ->
        openedCallback()
    result:
      finally: (callback) ->
        finallyCallback = callback
```

then in the test area:

```
  finallyCallback()

  expect (thing finally callback does)
    .toEqual (what you would expect)
```

Comment: I think you're missing a - in your arrow functions, so to speak, that would make `->` into `=>`, right? And I _think_ what you're adding is that he could replace `close: function( item ) {
        this.result.confirmCallBack( item );
    },` with `close: this.result.confirmCallBack,`, right?  I'm not real sure what the code as written is doing in the first snippet. (☉_☉)