# Mocking Modal instance in Angular with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test the opening of a modal in angular but running into this error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET app/templates/editComment/editComment.html
No more request expected
```

Here's my code I'm testing:

```
vm.editComment = function (comment) {
        vm.modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/editComment/editComment.html',
            controller: 'EditCommentCtrl as vm',
            comment: comment,
            resolve: {
                comment: function () {
                    return comment;
                }
            }
        }).result.then(function (result) {
            vm.getComments();
        });
    }
```

Test Setup:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $q, $sce) {
   q = $q;
   var stateParam = {id: 1};
   scope = $rootScope.$new();
   var Listmanager = "";



 var fakeModal = {
    result: {
        then: function(confirmCallback, cancelCallback) {
            //Store the callbacks for later when the user clicks on the OK or Cancel button of the dialog
            this.confirmCallBack = confirmCallback;
            this.cancelCallback = cancelCallback;
        }
    },
    close: function( item ) {
        //The user clicked OK on the modal dialog, call the stored confirm callback with the selected item
        this.result.confirmCallBack( item );
    },
    dismiss: function( type ) {
    //The user clicked cancel on the modal dialog, call the stored cancel callback
    this.result.cancelCallback( type );
}};

  var modalInstance = {
        open: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.open')
    }

  modalInstance.open.and.returnValue(fakeModal);




ctrl = $controller('CommentsCtrl', { $scope: scope, $modalInstance:                modalInstance, ds: dsMock, $stateParams: stateParam, $sce: $sce, Listmanager: Listmanager, ns: nsMock });
    }));
```

Here's my test:

```
it('edit comments should open modal', inject(function () {
        var comment = "test";
        ctrl.editComment(comment);
        scope.$apply();
        expect(modalInstance.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
```

I've looked at both [Testing AngularUI Bootstrap modal instance controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373220/angularjs-ui-bootstrap-testing-modal-instance-controller) and [Mocking $modal in AngularJS unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214868/angularjs-ui-bootstrap-mocking-modal-in-unit-test) to try and get some answers but nothing that I've tried has worked so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modal.open needs to return a promise, but also needs to be a spy in case you don't want a result.

If we only did:

```
open: jasmine.createSpy('modal.open')
```

it will work for most cases, but we want a promise so if we did this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $q, $sce) {
   q = $q;
   var stateParam = {id: 1};
   scope = $rootScope.$new();
   var Listmanager = "";

    modal = {
        open: jasmine.createSpy('modal.open').and.returnValue({ result: { then: jasmine.createSpy('modal.result.then') } }),
        close: jasmine.createSpy('modal.close'),
        dismiss: jasmine.createSpy('modal.dismiss')
    };

    ctrl = $controller('CommentsCtrl', { $scope: scope, $modal:modal, ds: dsMock, $stateParams: stateParam, $sce: $sce, Listmanager: Listmanager, ns: nsMock });
}));
```

It should work like a charm!