# access scope of modalInstance returned by ui-bootstrap $modal.open()

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

For a test, I want to create a modal instance, then access it's scope, using something like the following pseudo-codeL

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({ ... })
var scope = modalInstance.getScope()
```

Of course, the modalInstance returned by $modal.open() as described in https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal does not have a method like getScope().

Is there some other way to gain access to the scope object that a modal instance created?

This may be related to [24373220](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373220/angularjs-ui-bootstrap-testing-modal-instance-controller).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the link your provide, you can set your own scope for the modal, and then keep a reference on it:

```
var modalScope    = $scope.$new();
var modalInstance = $modal.open({scope: modalScope})
// You have a reference to the modal scope
```

Comment: You are right @floribon.  I should have thought about that.  I am trying to test a service that creates the scope inside it's method and returns a modal instance.  I should add a scope variable as an optional parameter to the method so that I can test it.  Thank you!