# uibModal provider unknown unitTest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm starting to learn how to do unitTesting with jasmine. I read a lot of in internet and SO but I can't solve my problem.

I have a directive which has a controller. That controller is using the service $uibModal to open a modal when I click an element. I'm trying to inject that service from my test but I can't. I read a lot of threads saying that I must pass an instance. I'm trying to do so but I can't. Please any help will be appreciated.

```
.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$uibModal', function($scope, $uibModal){
    var self = this;
    //OTHER CODE
    self.openMyModal = function(dataInput) {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            bindToController: true,
            templateUrl: 'app/myComponent/modals/component-modal.html',
            controllerAs: 'componentModalCtrl',
            controller: 'componentModalController',
            windowClass: 'semi-modal semi-modal--large',
            scope: $scope
        })
    }
    //OTHER CODE
}
```

This is the test where I'm trying to mock this modal.

```
beforeEach(function(){
    angular.mock.module('templates');
    angular.mock.module('app.components.myComponent');

    angular.mock.inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $templateCache, $controller){
        scope = $rootScope;
        modalInstance = { close: function(){}, dismiss: function(){}, open: function(){}
    };
    //Initializing element and doing compile and digest
    controller = $controller('myController', {$scope: scope, $uibModal: modalInstance});

})
```

I'm getting the error

> Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal.

Can I inject this service in another way? What I'm doing wrong?

P.S: I have read this [Testing AngularUI Bootstrap modal instance controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373220/testing-angularui-bootstrap-modal-instance-controller/24376344#24376344)

[Angular ui bootstrap $uibModalInstance breaks down unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482810/angular-ui-bootstrap-uibmodalinstance-breaks-down-unit-tests)

[Mocking $modal in AngularJS unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214868/mocking-modal-in-angularjs-unit-tests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it. It was a silly error. I imported an additional module that I was missing in my tests. After that I could mock my service and use it without any problem like this.

```
angular.mock.inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $templateCache, $controller, $uibModal){
    scope = $rootScope;
    uibModal = $uibModal;
    element = angular.element('<directive-tree input-tree=inputTree subsystem=subsystem></directive-tree>');
    $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    controller = $controller('directiveTreeController', {$scope: scope, $uibModal: uibModal});
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.service("$uibModal", function () {
        // mock methods here
    });
}));
```