# Karma-Jasmine: Testing the closing of a modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-jasmine

**THE SITUATION:**

I am testing the proper working of a modal in my Angular / Ionic app.

So far I can properly test the fact that the modal has been called, but I don't know how to test the proper closing of the modal.

Have made several attempts and read similar questions, but didn't find a  solution.

**THE CODE:**

**The controller:**

Code working fine in the app, it has just been refactored to facilitate the unit test.

```
$scope.open_login_modal = function() 
{
    var temp = $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html',{scope: $scope});

    temp.then(function(modal) { 
        $scope.modal_login = modal;
        $scope.modal_login.show();
    });
};

$scope.close_login_modal = function() 
{
    $scope.modal_login.hide();
};
```

**The test:**

The first test (open modal) is working fine and passes. The second test I don't know how to do it.

```
describe('App tests', function() 
{
    beforeEach(module('my_app.controllers'));

    // mocking the .then method of $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl (it works)
    function fakeTemplate() 
    {
        return { 
            then: function(modal){
                $scope.modal_login = modal;
            }
        }
    }

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_)
    {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();

        $ionicModal = 
        {
            fromTemplateUrl: jasmine.createSpy('$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl').and.callFake(fakeTemplate)
        }; 

        var controller = $controller('MainCtrl', { $scope: $scope, $rootScope: $rootScope, $ionicModal: $ionicModal });
    }));


    describe('Modal tests', function() 
    {
        it('should open login modal', function() 
        {
            $scope.open_login_modal();

            expect($ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect($ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl.calls.count()).toBe(1);
        });

        it('should close login modal', function() 
        {
            $scope.close_login_modal();
            // How can i test here that the modal has been close?
        });
    });

});
```

**THE ERROR:**

This is the error message: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined`

**THE QUESTION:**

How can I test the close of the modal?
How can I be sure that the function `hide()` has been properly called?

It has to do with the declaring of the modal in the test?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

This answer properly replied to the question 'how to test the closing of a modal' giving the right solution to include before the opening of the modal.
If you want to know how to properly spy a modal i have asked in a separate question:

[Karma-Jasmine: How to properly spy on a Modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367354/karma-jasmine-how-to-properly-spy-on-a-modal)

The given answer give also the rule how to spy a premise in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your close test requires the modal login to have been opened and since this is not happening you are getting that error:

I would rewrite you test something like:

```
describe('Modal tests', function() {
  beforeEach(function(){
    $scope.open_login_modal();
  });
  it('should open login modal', function() {
    expect($ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect($ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl.calls.count()).toBe(1);
  });
  it('should close login modal', function() {
    $scope.close_login_modal();
    spyOn($scope.modal_login, 'hide');
    expect($scope.modal_login.hide()).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

So both tests require the the open_login_modal function to be called and so I added to a beforeEach. You will also need a spy on the hide function for the modal too.

Comment: Thank you! You know how can i properly write that spy?

Comment: I just edited my answer with a spyOn call, try that, should be something along those lines anyway

Comment: Unfortunately i get $scope.modal_login.hide is not a function. I think i am missing something when i declare the modal in the test.

Comment: I think this post may give you some clues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214868/angularjs-ui-bootstrap-mocking-modal-in-unit-test although it's for a bootstrap modal the flow of the test is similar

Comment: Thank you. I have made a separate question concentrated only about how to spy a modal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367354/karma-jasmine-how-to-properly-spy-on-a-modal  Now all the doubts are gone :)