# angularjs jasmine promise testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, promise

I'm trying to test my login controller, which should send users' login/password to the service and say if it exists in the service. Here is my code:

```
    describe('LoginController', function() {
    beforeEach(module('task6'));

    var $controller, LoginService;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _LoginService_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        LoginService = _LoginService_;
    }));

    describe('LoginController.submitLogin', function() {
        it('tests if such user exists', function() {
            var $scope = {};
            var controller = $controller('LoginController', 
                                         {$scope: $scope});
            controller.loginField = 'John';
            controller.password = 'Smith';
            LoginService.signIn(controller.loginField, 
                                controller.password)
            .then(function(logged) {
                expect(true).toBe(false);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

But it seems like tests in ".then" function never executed. It passes all the tests even with these conditions.

Comment: have you tried to read official documentation - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#testing ? Than you can try to read some article like e.g: http://brianmcd.com/2014/03/27/a-tip-for-angular-unit-tests-with-promises.html

Comment: Yo, you can check this article (written by me) https://ath3nd.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/15/. Of course it is Restangular specific, but restangular is a service which uses promises so it should be close to what you want to achieve. Also, you can take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367354/karma-jasmine-how-to-properly-spy-on-a-modal/33367678#33367678

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your are testing asynchronous code so you need to make the test asynchronous using done as follows ...

```
it('tests if such user exists', function(done) {
            .....
            LoginService.signIn(controller.loginField, 
                            controller.password)
            .then(function(logged) {
                expect(true).toBe(false);
                // done();
            }).catch(function(failure) {
                expect(true).toBe(true);
                done();
            })

        });
    });
```

done makes it wait for the promise to resolve / reject.
if it doesn't resolve or reject within 2 seconds (default) then the test will fail.

Comment: Thank you! But somehow this doesn't work for me. I'm pretty sure that I'm doing the same thing you did, and I still get "Success" message on all tests... `LoginService.signIn(controller.loginField,
             controller.password)
   .then(function(logged) {
    expect(false).toBe(true);
   })
   .catch(function(failure) {
    expect(true).toBe(false);
    done();
   });`

Comment: ok your test code assume LoginService.signIn is returning a promise. Is that correct? maybe you can provide that code

Comment: PS did you add ... it('tests if such user exists', function(done) ... notice the done here too - this is what makes the test async - the calls to done in the promise resolution merely denote the async test is complete

Comment: I guess this could really be my problem. :) Here is the code ` function signIn(loginField, password) {
  return getUsers()
   .then(function(users) {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
     if (users[i].login == loginField && users[i].password == password) {
      $rootScope.logged = true;
      $rootScope.user = users[i].login;
      $location.path('/courses');
      return true;
     }
    }
    return false;
   })
   .catch(function () {
    console.log("Error: Users array wasn't retrieved from the server");
    return false;
   });  
 }`

Comment: ok i will add another answer to show you how to return a promise from signIn function

Comment: Thank you! You were totally right, I have forgotten to add `function(done)`. :) Now tests are always failed because of timeouts, but this is a totally different problem, I guess. So thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function signIn(username, password) {
   /// THIS RETURNS A PROMISE BECAUSE $http returns a promise. Thus you can call THEN method on the return value because all promises have a THEN method.
   return $http.post('myserver', {username:username, password:password});
}



// Another approach using $q

function signIn(username, password) {
   var defer = $q.defer();
   if (username==="fred" && password==="mypass") {
        defer.resolve("nice one");
   } else {
        defer.reject("oh dear");
   }
   return defer.promise;
}
```

Here both approaches return a promise. so now, when I call the function I can call THEN on its return value (because the return value is a promise) ...

```
signIn("fred", "badpass").then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(function(failure) {
    console.log(failure);
});
```