# Angular unit test for bootstrap pop-up

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I want to write the angular unit test unit test for the following function,

```
$scope.addDataList = function () {
    $scope.IsDefault = false;
    $scope.IsPATsDefault = false;
    $('#plAddEditCopy').modal('show');
}
```

The `addDataList` opens the bootstrap popup. How do I use `SpyOn` on the third line of the function `$('#plAddEditCopy').modal('show')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To spy on modal you can do following

```
//spyOn(object, methodName) where object.method() is a function
spyOn($('#yourelementId'), 'modal')

expect($('#yourElementId').modal).toHaveBeenCalled()();
```

refer [Jasmine spy on](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/spy-on-javascript-methods-using-the-jasmine-testing-framework.html#fbid=jEBm_elc7nM)

Comment: or refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214868/mocking-modal-in-angularjs-unit-tests

Comment: My Test case is as follows :-   it('Test Case ', function () {
        spyOn($('#plAddEditCopy'), 'modal')
        var AddNewEntry = $(element).find("#lnkAddPriceList")[0];
        AddNewEntry.click();
        expect($('#plAddEditCopy').modal)..toBeCalled();
    });    but getting error   TypeError: expect(...).toBeCalled is not a function

Comment: updated plz use expect(foo.setBar).toHaveBeenCalled()

Comment: already tried with toHaveBeenCalled() getting Error :-Expected a spy, but got Function.
 Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalled()

Answer (score 0):

Try using following

**JS code**

```
  describe(function() {
    var form;

    beforeEach(function() {
      html= $('<div id="plAddEditCopy" class="modal fade" role="dialog">'+
      '<div class="modal-dialog"></div></div>');
      $(document.body).append(html);
    });

    it('your test', function() {
    // call your function
    // so that will open modal and cover that code
    // like 
    ctrl.addDataList();
    expect();
    })

    afterEach(function() {
      // remove it
    });
  });
```

Comment: it('Test to check pop up is showing or not', function () {
    
        var iElement = $(element).find("#lnkAddPriceList")[0];

        iElement.click();
        // which is calling addDataList()        
    });     my question is what property  should i test in expect()

Comment: cover scope variables only

Comment: I am still not clear      i have already loaded template so the div id plAddEditCopy is present in the template is there any way to spyOn on the  $('#plAddEditCopy').modal('show');  just like i have done in the following test      :-  it('Test to check the Show rule button is working or not ', function () {
        spyOn(BootstrapDialog, 'show').and.callThrough();
        var iElement = $(element).find('#lnkScoreCalculation')[0];
        //console.log(iElement)
        iElement.click();
        scope.$digest();
      
        expect(BootstrapDialog.show).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

Comment: This will add html to dom and your error will be get resolved

Comment: Html is already present in the DOM i am using templateCache to load the html page : - template = $templateCache.get('**/SS.html');

Comment: I am still not clear i have already loaded template so the div id plAddEditCopy is present in the template is there any way to spyOn on the $('#plAddEditCopy').modal('show'); just like i have done in the following test :- it('Test to check the Show rule button is working or not ', function () { spyOn(BootstrapDialog, 'show').and.callThrough(); var iElement = $(element).find('#lnkScoreCalculation')[0]; //console.log(iElement) iElement.click(); scope.$digest(); expect(BootstrapDialog.show).toHaveBeenCalled(); });