# How to mock results from uibmodal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, karma-jasmine

I have below code:

```
vm.data = [{name: 'test-1'},{name: 'test-2'}];

function addRecords(data) {
    vm.data.push(data);
}

function openPopup() {

    $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'modal-popup/modal-popup.html',
        controller: 'ModalPopupController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        resolve: {
            id: _.constant('123')
        }
    }).result.then(addRecords);
}
```

Trying to mock this, Below are the declarations:

```
let allData = [{name: 'test-1'},{name: 'test-2'}];
let data = {name: 'test-3'};

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$q_, _$rootScope_, _$componentController_, _$uibModal_) {
        $q = _$q_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = _$componentController_;
        $uibModal = _$uibModal_;

        spyOn($uibModal, 'open').and.returnValue({
            result: function() {
                return $q.when(data);
            }
        });

        vm = controller('bvcListings', {
            $q,
            data: allData,
            $uibModal
        });

        $scope.$apply();
    }));

    describe('openPopup', function () {
        it('should add records on modal results', function () {
            vm.openPopup();
            expect($uibModal.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
```

Expectation is, it should add: `{name: 'test-3'}` as result to existing array.

Spy on modal open is working fine, but after results fetched, its not entering addRecords function. What am i doing wrong?

What changes need to be done here to get inside callback function after results retrieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.result.then` callback method will get call only when you call `modalInstance.close` method, also don't forgot to pass `data` from `close` method something like `modalInstance.close(data)`.

Before proceeding to test you need to do one change inside `openPopup` function. It should return `$uibModal.open` which basically returns newly created modal's instance. Thereafter you can easily have a control over modal to call `dismiss`/`close` method whenever needed.

```
function openPopup() {
    vm.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'modal-popup/modal-popup.html',
        controller: 'ModalPopupController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        resolve: {
            id: _.constant('123')
        }
    });

   vm.modalInstance.result.then(addRecords);
}
```

**Spec**

```
$uibModal = _$uibModal_;
var data = {name: 'test-3'};
//creating fake modal which will help you to mock 
var fakeModal = {
    result: {
        then: function(confirmCallback) {
            //Store the callbacks
            this.confirmCallBack = confirmCallback;
        }
    },
    close: function( item ) {
        //The user clicked OK on the modal dialog
        this.result.confirmCallBack( item );
    }
};
spyOn($uibModal, 'open').and.returnValue(fakeModal);

describe('It should data to vm.data when popup closed', function () {
    it('should add records on modal results', function () {
       vm.data = [{name: 'test-1'},{name: 'test-2'}];
       let data = {name: 'test-3'};
       vm.openPopup();
       expect($uibModal.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
       vm.modalInstance.close(data);
       expect(vm.data.length).toBe(4);
       expect(vm.data[3]).toBe(data);
    });
});
```

> **Note:** `fakeModal` has been referred from [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21370703/2435473)

Comment: `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (near '...}).result.then(addRecords);...')`

Comment: @Mithun can you show me how you instantiate controller instance?? You may not be passing `$uibModal` to controller instance

Comment: Edited my question @Pankaj, plz check

Comment: I used to use such mocks, but actually there is no need to mock promise with something that is not promise as it greatly reduces your testing possibilities.

Comment: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'modalInstance.close')`

Comment: @Mithun would you mind me to provide a simple plunker.. I would wish to dig into this.. something small thing seems to missing..

Comment: `'modalInstance => ', undefined` when i tried to print @PankajParkar because its not returning anything to initialize to variable from `openPopup ` function. So, should i inject `uibmodalinstance` instead?

Comment: @Mithun no you shouldn't be injecting `$uibModalinstance`.. can you please provide me a plunker?

Comment: I highly appreciate your efforts, but i am trying my level best to fix this asap. If not possible, ill create a plnkr for you.

Comment: `Error: spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for open()` My bad i was not returning uibmodal. I have corrected inside my code, but i am getting this error. Plz help

Comment: Plz provide me a plunker.so that I can dig further

Comment: I finally managed to get it work with minor tweak. Editing my question with answer, plz check Pankaj. But this is an excellent answer ill accept this though

Comment: @Mithun Glad to hear that.. I don't see any edit.. you can propose an edit to my answer as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> Continuing with @Pankajs answer.
>
> Here is a tweak which i made and got that worked.

```
function openPopup() {
    vm.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'modal-popup/modal-popup.html',
        controller: 'ModalPopupController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        resolve: {
            id: _.constant('123')
        }
    }).result.then(addRecords);
}
```

**Spec**

```
describe('modalpopup', function () {
    it('should add records on modal results', function () {
        vm.data = [{name: 'test-1'},{name: 'test-2'}];
        let data = {name: 'test-3'};
        vm.openPopup();
        expect($uibModal.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
        vm.modalInstance.close(data);
        expect(vm.data.length).toBe(4);
        expect(vm.data[3]).toBe(data);
    });
});
```

Worked like charm for me. And i consier Pankajs answer as well which was almost 90% gave solution to my problem.

Comment: Still I don't understand, exactly where the tweak had happened??

Comment: wouldn't vm.data[3] be outofbound exception. vm.data[2] would point to it

Answer (score 0):

add `$rootScope.$digest();` to resolve promises (like $q.when())

```
vm.openPopup();
expect($uibModal.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
$rootScope.$digest(); >> triggers your callback
```

Comment: How could this will call `result.then` method of opened modal?

Comment: look his mock: spyOn($uibModal, 'open').and.returnValue({
            result: function() {
                return $q.when(data);
            }
        });

Comment: then it should be `and.returnValue({ result: { then: {function() { return $q.when(data); } }});` again coming back to mock which I provided :p